# Database update on id deleted

Tags: android, sqlite, increment

Can someone tell  me what is wrong with coding below. Why I can not update next positions?

```
     public static void deleteItemsFromProduct(long nomer) {

        cursor_child = DataSourceChild.queryAllinChild();

        if (cursor_child != null) {

            par = new String[]{String.valueOf(nomer)};

            db_child.delete(DBHelperChild.TABLE_ITEMS_AND_PRICES, DBHelperChild.COLUMN_NOMER + "=?", par);


Prod.setProdId(nomer);

cv_child = new ContentValues();
cv_child.put(DBHelperChild.COLUMN_NOMER, Prod.getProdId());

par = new String[]{String.valueOf(nomer+1)};

int updCount = db_child.update(DBHelperChild.TABLE_ITEMS_AND_PRICES, cv_child, DBHelperChild.COLUMN_NOMER + "=?", par);

Log.d(LOG_TAG, "updated rows count = " + updCount);

            if (cursor_child.moveToFirst()) {

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Left in the table for items and prices: ---");

                do {

                    Log.d(LOG_TAG,
                            "item id = " + cursor_child.getInt(item_and_price_idColIndex)
                            + ", item name = " + cursor_child.getString(item_ColIndex)
                            + ", item price = " + cursor_child.getInt(price_ColIndex)
                            + ", product nomer = " + cursor_child.getInt(nomer_ColIndex));

                } while (cursor_child.moveToNext());
            } else {
            }

        } else {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Cursor is null");
            // закрываем курсор
            cursor_child.close();

        }
    }
```

The idea is to delete set of items in the list while getting id (nomer) from another list. This code updates only the next id nomer after deleted but not others down the list.
Thank you.

Comment: i don't understand the question. format your code, comment in english, and explain what is not working

Comment: and what is cursor_child anyway ?

Comment: (which you probably need to requery)

Comment: if you wanna help please see the following link with full explanationshttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156544/database-update-and-id-incerment-when-list-item-deleted#comment17899592_13156544